# Nested Quantifier: What is the right solution?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

***Use quantifiers and logical connectives*** to express the fact
that a quadratic polynomial with real number coefficients
has **at most** two real roots

Solution:

$\forall a \forall b \forall c ((a \neq 0 \lor b \neq 0) \rightarrow \exists x(x = \frac {-b + \sqrt {b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} \lor x = \frac {-b - \sqrt {b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}) \land \forall y ((y = \frac {-b + \sqrt {b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} \lor y = \frac {-b - \sqrt {b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}) \rightarrow y =x))$

Why this solution is not right? Please explain.

Comment: The statement doesn't mention a quadratic polynomial....

Comment: Thank you Greg and TheSimpliFire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write something like

> $\forall f(X) \in \mathbb{R}[X]\forall a, b , c \in \mathbb{R}: ((\deg f = 2) \land  (f(a)=f(b)=f(c)=0)) \Rightarrow ((b = c)\lor (a = b)\lor(a = c))$

or alternatively

> $\forall a,b,c,x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}: ((a \neq 0) \land  (ax^2+bx+c=ay^2+by+c=az^2+bz+c=0)) \Rightarrow ((x = y)\lor (x = z) \lor(z = y))$

Comment: Thank you lambda